# How do I use ajax and javascript to build an image portfolio

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, colorbox

I am trying to launch an image portfolio by pressing a thumbnail. The code to build the portfolio does not get run until the user presses the thumbnail. Here is what I have.

I am essentially trying implement one these into my website.
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

The workflow is:
1. A list of portfolios is displayed with a thumbnail
2. When the thumbnail is selected, the portfolio is built and displayed.

The code below works as it should. When the thumbnail is selected, the portfolio is launched and all is good. This was tested with a loop and executed each time the page is loaded.

```
<a class="group2" href="'.$cacheDataPath . $thumbnail.'">
<img style="display: inline-block" src="'.$cacheDataPath . $thumbnail.'" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

In order to build the portfolio when selected (and not each time the page is loaded) I am using this which is working.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="buildColorboxPortfolio()">

function buildColorboxPortfolio() {
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/build_portfolio.php',
       data:{action:'test'},
       async:false,
       complete: function (response) {
       jQuery('#output').html(response.responseText);
      }
    //      alert(html);
  });
```

}

From here what needs to happen is a url is created that looks like this. It is generated in the php script. Then launched.

```
<a class="group2" href="'.$cacheDataPath . $thumbnail.'">
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<?php
$html = '<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset=\'utf-8\'/>
            <title>Colorbox Examples</title>
            <style>
            </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/colorbox-master/example1/colorbox.css" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/colorbox-master/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
            <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                            //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
                            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:\'group3\', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:\'group2\', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                            $("#click").click(function(){
                                    $(\'#click\').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                                    return false;
                            });
                    });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>

            <a class="group3" href="/colorbox-master/content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">TEST</a>
            <p><a class="group3" href="/colorbox-master/content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child"></a>TEST</p>
            <p><a class="group3" href="/colorbox-master/content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult"></a></p>
    </body>
</html>';
echo $html;
```

Can someone tell me how to get this working? The html is returned correctly, and I can press the TEST url which will launch the portfolio correctly...but I need it to go automatically on the original onclick.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to first stop wrapping all the HTML within a PHP string. It's not necessary.

To fix the issue, don't `return false;` in the jQuery `#click()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried removing the return false; but nothing changed. In regards to the html, thanks for the advise. It will get cleaned up once I get it the portfolio to launch.

Comment: remove the "()" from the onclick so it looks like `onclick="buildColorboxPortfolio"`

Comment: No joy. Without those it doesn't call the function at all. What about the divs? Right now pressing the Thumbnail returns TEST. Due to this. $html .= '<div id="output"> Then the TEST url launches the portfolio correctly. Do I need the div in my main script?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible...but this needs to load when the thumbnail is pushed. Now it loads when pressing TEST.  <a class="group3" href="/colorbox-master/content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">TEST</a>

Comment: Replace `href="javascript:void(0)"` to `href="#"`

Comment: Nope. Didn't do it. Thanks though.